# Android right alignment not working using Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_OPPOSITE

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-edittext, spannablestring

I am trying to apply AlignmentSpan such that `Title` is left aligned whereas `1234` is algined to the right side in the `hint` of a `TextInputLayout`:

var remaining = 1234
holder.fieldContainer.hint =  buildSpannedString {
inSpans(AlignmentSpan.Standard(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL)) {
append("Title ")
}
inSpans(AlignmentSpan.Standard(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_OPPOSITE)) {
append("$remaining")
}
}

This doesn't seem to work and the `Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_OPPOSITE` isn't doing anything:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Code for layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fieldContainer"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextLabel"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/minheightoffield"
    >
    <com.pranapps.hack.CustomInputEditText
        android:gravity="top|start"
        android:paddingTop="40dp"
        android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/sidepaddingforhnitemshorizontal"
        android:id="@+id/field"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/minheightoffield"
        />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Yeah, that just does not work, despite the examples you might see that claim so. `AlignmentSpan` is a `ParagraphStyle`, not a `CharacterStyle`. They would have to be on separate lines, which defeats the purpose. I don't believe I ever did find a decent solution to this that didn't involve manipulating the text drawing at the `View`/`Canvas` level, or adding another `Drawable` or `View` to the overlay. At least, I don't think it can be done with spans only.

Comment: @MikeM. I was afraid that was going to be the case. If you post that as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Oh, I'm good. Nothin' huge. We might wait to see if someone else has a good idea, 'cause this is still something I'd like to see an elegant solution for. Thank you, though. I appreciate the offer. Cheers!